# Why does $\aleph_{\alpha+1} \leq 2^{\aleph_\alpha} $ hold true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I proved in $\mathbb{L}$ $2^{\aleph_\alpha} \leq  \aleph_{\alpha+1}$.
But I don't have an idea why $\aleph_{\alpha+1} \leq 2^{\aleph_\alpha} $?

Comment: The power set of a set has greater cardinality than the set (Cantor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just Cantor's theorem.  We know that $2^{\aleph_\alpha}>\aleph_\alpha$.  Since $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ is the least cardinal greater than $\aleph_\alpha$, $2^{\aleph_\alpha}\geq\aleph_{\alpha+1}$.

(This does not require you to be working in $L$.  However, it does require the axiom of choice, since without choice you only know that $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ is the least *well-orderable* cardinality greater than $\aleph_\alpha$.)

Answer (score 4):

By Cantor's theorem, $2^{\aleph_\alpha}$ is *larger than* $\aleph_\alpha$.

By definition, $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ is the *smallest* ordinal that is larger than $\aleph_\alpha$.

Comment: A silly question : how do we know "the smallest ordinal larger than" is well-defined ? (not asking about the continuum hypothesis, but the abstract idea of constructing such an iterated sequence from any initial ordinal)

Comment: @user1952009: Hartogs' theorem says that there is at least one ordinal $\beta$ that is larger than $\aleph_\alpha$. The set of ordinals $\le\beta$ is (like every set of ordinals) well-ordered, and therefore $\{\gamma\le\beta\mid |\gamma|>|\aleph_\alpha| \}$ has a minimal element which we call $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$. This is _globally_ minimal because anything else that is $>\aleph_\alpha$ will either be $\le \beta$ (and thus $\ge\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ by construction) or $>\beta$ (and so $>\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ by transitivity).

Comment: Yes I got it this is the minimal element.